# Step counter plugin gives error when the stop() method called after first time

Tags: cordova, typescript, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins, ionic-native

I have an issue in doing a step counter in ionic v3.x,
This is the code

```
import { Stepcounter } from '@ionic-native/stepcounter';

startPedometer() {

if (this.buttonIcon === 'md-walk') {
  this.buttonIcon = "md-man";
  this.startbuttonDisabled = false
  this.stopbuttonDisabled = true
  let startOffset = 0
  this.stepcounter.start(startOffset).then((res: any) => {
    this.success("Started : " + res)
  }).catch((err) => this.failure(err))
}
else if (this.buttonIcon === 'md-man') {
  this.buttonIcon = "md-walk";
  this.stopbuttonDisabled = false
  this.startbuttonDisabled = true
  this.stepcounter.stop().then((res: any) => {
    this.count = res
  }).catch((err) => this.failure(err))
}
}

ionViewDidEnter(){
this.stepcounter.getStepCount().then((res:any)=>{
  console.log("---------counts-----------"+JSON.stringify(res));
  this.count = res
})
}
```

I have get the following error

```
service not registered: net.texh.cordovapluginstepcounter.CordovaStepCounter$1@36cef5f
```

Please help me out.
any suggestion is appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: Did you try to import `https://github.com/ihadeed/cordova-plugin-stepcounter.git` instead of `https://github.com/texh/cordova-plugin-stepcounter.git` ?

Comment: Thanks for this, but i actually dropped the idea of using the stepcounter plugin because it doesn't support all android devices, so that i used google fit api for counting the steps of user

Answer (score -1):

There is a period of time between you converting the button to the "stop" button using `md-man` and the actual start request completing.

Annotated explanation:

```
if (this.buttonIcon === 'md-walk') {

  // Change buttons (instant)

  this.stepcounter.start(startOffset).then((res: any) => {

    // The counter has actually started (remember this is async)

  }).catch((err) => this.failure(err))
}
```

To solve this, you should enable the stop button within the `then` for "start completed".

Comment: Thanks for reply
But the problem is not there.
did you see the error that i wrote under the code?